# When telling a grammar rule, should I use plural or singular?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Alice doesn't know about linking verb at all, so she asks Michael to explain the meaning and the usage of linking verb.

Michael says

> **A linking verb is a verb** that is used to describe a state of being
>
> **Linking verbs are a group of verbs** that are used to describe a state of being

which one should I use, plural or singular?

Comment: Both sentence are grammatically correct, but they look odd and kind of unnatural. Would you please tell us what is the intended idea that you want to convey?

Comment: Insert **used** after each phrase in bold if you want the sentences to sound normal and not distract from your actual question.

Comment: As for your actual question, there is no way of knowing *which* you ***should*** use. It's a matter of context. Are you talking about the general concept, or about a countable group?

Answer (score 1):

The sentences could also be written as:

> A linking verb is used to describe a state of being
>
> Linking verbs are used to describe a state of being

Both are grammatically correct. Either one would be fine.